# Auditor Accounts In SharePoint and SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, auditing

We have an audit happening across our content.  Is there a way to set up an account in SharePoint on-premises (2013 & 2010) and SharePoint Online that we could give the Auditors access to everything but in read-only?

Comment: No, that functionality does not exist in SharePoint Online and if you can add to your question about what needs to be audited, there is likely a much better way to do so in O365 than manually reviewing sites.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to give the auditors access to everything but in read-only permission.

In SharePoint on-premise,only site-collection owners can run audit log reports.

In SharePoint online,you need to be a member of the default Site Collections Administrators group or a farm administrator to run Audit Log Reports.

More information for your reference:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-audit-data-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2#ID0EAADAAA=SharePoint_Online